# What MAC, IP and IPv6 addresses should I use as example for testing and documentation?

Tags: mac-address, ip-address

There are [example.com](http://example.com) or [example.org](http://example.org) domains used for documentation.

There are MCC `001` and MNC `01` used for testing equipment in cell networks.

Are there MAC, IP and IPv6 addresses that are intended to use or used conventionally for testing purposes and documentation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To quote from RFC 5737:

> The blocks 192.0.2.0/24 (TEST-NET-1), 198.51.100.0/24 (TEST-NET-2),
> and 203.0.113.0/24 (TEST-NET-3) are provided for use in
> documentation.

And RFC 5156:

> The 2001:db8::/32 are the documentation addresses [RFC3849].  They
> are used for documentation purposes such as user manuals, RFCs, etc.
> Addresses within this block should not appear on the public Internet.

And of course, RFC 7042:

> 0x0042 is a protocol number under the IANA OUI (that is,
> 00-00-5E-00-42) to be used for documentation purposes.

Comment: That's great that you know what to search in Google better than me. I tried significantly more that 30 seconds and didn't search anything. Thank you!

Comment: Really? "ip address for documentation" pulls up everything you need to know.

Comment: I desperately tried various forms with word `test`... It happens.